# The representation of MOS size

Tags: mosfet

Some paper will mark the size of MOS,like \$ \frac{40}{4}\$ below,and MOS have minimum size for any process,take U18 for example,its minimum size is W=240nm L=180nm.

i want to ask why don't author reduce fraction,i mean write\$ \frac{40}{4}\$ as \$ \frac{10}{1}\$,or is the \$ \frac{40}{4}\$ means that the MOS width is 240nm*40 and length is 180nm*4 so it can't be written as \$ \frac{10}{1}\$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any true standard about this. Hence it could be that a author does indeed represent the ratio of W and L with this.

However, I don't think that is generally the case (at least, I've never run into that). What it does mean is that the size in \$\mu m\$, in other words, that transistor would be 40 \$\mu m\$ wide and 4 \$\mu m\$ long. The reason it is kept as a ratio is because in the simplified equations for the \$g_m\$ of a MOS in saturation, the ratio between width and length is important, but at the same time, the Early effect is mainly determined by the length.

It is possible that an author is also referring to the size in \$nm\$. Context should make it clear which one it is.

Comment: I have my doubts about whether it's 4 nm long. Isn't 7 nm the current cutting-edge technology?

Comment: I should have phrased it differently. I was not referring to this specific case, but that there is no law that papers giving sizes will be in micrometers, nanometers is also possible when they are working in sub-micrometer technologies.